# Android GCM - "Handling Received Data"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Android documentation for GCM [here](http://pages.citebite.com/e3s6b5w4ecev) states

> that key-pair values in the data parameter, they are available as
>   extras in this intent, with the keys being the extra names.

```
private void handleMessage(Intent intent) {
    // server sent 2 key-value pairs, score and time
    String score = intent.getExtra("score");
    String time = intent.getExtra("time");
    // generates a system notification to display the score and time
}
```

But intent.getExtra() method does not accept an argument

```
public Bundle getExtras ()

Since: API Level 1
Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.

Returns
the map of all extras previously added with putExtra(), or null if none have been added.
```

**MyQuestion**

How to retrieve a 'String' from the GCM message in `onMessage()` method?

P.S `onMessage(Context context, Intent intent): Called when your server sends a message to GCM, and GCM delivers it to the device. If the message has a payload, its contents are available as extras in the intent.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use:

```
intent.getExtras().getString("score");
intent.getExtras().getString("time");
```

Be careful about the type, it can be:

```
intent.getExtras().getInt("myvar");
```

Or some other types. Take a look at [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Comment: +1, Why you directed me towards Bundle. Is your answer drawn from credible source?

Comment: Because getExtras() provides you a Bundle.